# Why is my error not kicking in when I execute my procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is my code that I have :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('spUpdateProductDiscount') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
    GO

CREATE PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
    (@ProductID INT,    @DiscountPercent INT)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY 
        UPDATE Products
        SET DiscountPercent = @DiscountPercent
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @DiscountPercent <= 0
            PRINT 'The value for this column DiscountPercent must be a positive number';
    END CATCH
END;
```

```
EXEC spUpdateProductDiscount 1999, -15.00
```

I don't know why my `PRINT` statement isn't kicking in. I have it set to if `@DiscountPercent` is less than or equal to 0 so I don't understand why the `PRINT` statement is not kicking in but it is changing the row to a `DiscountPercent` of -15.00.

Comment: `I don't know why my PRINT statement isn't kicking in` - because the `UPDATE` does not throw an exception?

Comment: Why do you expect the `UPDATE` to throw an exception?

Comment: Do you have a constraint or trigger that defines that discount percent cannot be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to Gordon's proposition of adding a constraint, we could also just check the parameter.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('spUpdateProductDiscount') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
    GO

CREATE PROC spUpdateProductDiscount
    (@ProductID INT,    @DiscountPercent INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @DiscountPercent <= 0 BEGIN
        PRINT 'The value for this column DiscountPercent must be a positive number';
    END ELSE BEGIN
        UPDATE Products
        SET DiscountPercent = @DiscountPercent
        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
    END
END;
```

Comment: Thank you I added a constraint but I did not switch the statements around

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you need to add a constraint?

```
alter table products add constraint chk_discount_percent check (discountpercent > 0)
```